# Need to search and replace image path

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update image paths in my SQL database. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_content` = replace(`post_content`,'%src="http://www.theworldeffect.com/.a/%"%','src="http://www.domainname.com/timages/%.jpg"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace() will not do regex matches for you. You can only use it replace a given string with another static string, for example

```
replace(`post_content`, 'src="http://www.theworldeffect.com/.a/',
                        'src="http://www.domainname.com/timages/')
```

This will only replace the prefix, but that might be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

from

http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, don't think you can use % in this way as a wildcard. Can you do it without?